# Regular expression in data annotation not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this data annotation in my class

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduce a number!")]
 [RegularExpression("[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
   public int number { get; set; }
```

The first data annotation works great but the second one doesn't work, if I introduce a letter or something that is not a number, it shows me the default message...any ideas?

It shows the value 'foo' is not valid for number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]

Comment: Nope it shows me the default The value 'j' is not valid for number =(

Answer (score 0):

by any change are you using jquery 1.5? iirc the unobtrusive validation is broken for that version if you are using the unobtrusive validation that comes with a new mvc project. IIRC I use the same expression as the poster about and it works for  me.

Answer (score -1):

First it try to convert to int since the datatype is int and therefore u see default message. If u use datatype string then ur regex will work.